# Как увеличить количество возвращаемых писем с помощью imap?

Tags: python-3.x, gmail, imap

Есть код, который логинится в почту, ищет там письма с определенной даты от определенного отправителя. В ответ я всегда получаю только 50 айди писем, как можно увеличить этот лимит?

```py
import imaplib
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
imap.login(user, password)
imap.select('inbox')
mails = imap.search(None, f"(HEADER FROM '{sender}' (SINCE 20-DEC-2022))")  # тут всегда только 50 писем
```

Comment: Мне не удалось воспроизвести указанную проблему. Я немного упростил поиск: `mails = imap.search(None, '(SINCE 20-DEC-2022)')` и получил 86 идентификаторов. То есть по факту лимита "50" нет.